# Move file to folder

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need some help with moving a file.

I'm trying to create a batch file that will resize images and overwrite the file smaller sized file.
The resize part can't have source and destination as the same filename, so I thought I could set a temp folder and move it back.

```
@echo off
set "source_folder=c:\src"
set "result_folder_1=c:\res1"

SET COPYCMD=/Y
:start
if exist %source_folder%\*.jpg (
    TIMEOUT /T 2 >nul
    for %%a in ("%source_folder%\*jpg") do (
    call scale.bat -source "%%~fa" -target "%result_folder_1%\%%~nxa" -max-height 1000 -max-width 1000 -keep-ratio yes -force yes
        TIMEOUT /T 5
    echo /Y "%result_folder_1%\%%~nxa" "%%~a"
        move /Y "%result_folder_1%\%%~nxa" "%%~a"
        del "%%~fa"
    )
)
goto start
```

The above resizes the file and places it in res folder, then the move is done, but I don't know where the file ends up, it's not where it should at least.

This is the output of the cmd window and it seems the move/echo is correct(?).

```
Waiting for 0 seconds, press a key to continue ...
/Y "c:\res1\details5.jpg" "c:\src\details5.jpg"
        1 file(s) moved.

Waiting for 0 seconds, press a key to continue ...
/Y "c:\res1\details6.jpg" "c:\src\details6.jpg"
        1 file(s) moved.

Waiting for 0 seconds, press a key to continue ...
/Y "c:\res1\details7.jpg" "c:\src\details7.jpg"
        1 file(s) moved.

Waiting for 0 seconds, press a key to continue ...
/Y "c:\res1\details8.jpg" "c:\src\details8.jpg"
        1 file(s) moved.

Waiting for 0 seconds, press a key to continue ...
/Y "c:\res1\details9.jpg" "c:\src\details9.jpg"
        1 file(s) moved.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Well, why do you delete the file after moving it?? *N. B.:* The `if exist` line should read `if exist "%source_folder%\*.jpg"` (quotation), and the `for` loop should read `for %%a in ("%source_folder%\*.jpg") do` (file pattern)…

Comment: Your logic is a little flawed here. :). You are creating a file in the destination, then move it back to the source, then you delete it again. The biggest problem here is that even if you do not delete the files, they will always exist in the source directory and you will always do the conversion on the already converted files.

Comment: Yes.. I was working on this file for a few months ago then I picked it up again today and had forgotten that previously it was meant to resize files placed in the source folder as a folder watcher and delete the source file. Now I wanted to adapt it to move the resized file to overwrite the source file. So a mistake on my part for not reading my code before editing and eventually posting the question. Sorry for this.

Comment: Before I updated and undelete my answer, why do you require the files back in the source dir with the same name? This will not work because you will then always do the conversion on the same files. Either there needs to be indicators in the name to allow them to be excluded, or you need to place them in a different directory to the source.

Comment: Umm.. well. In the past the quality control at work used cameras to take pictures and the pictures was a few KB. Now they got iPhones and each image is 2.5-3.5 MB which means my folder has grown from about 200-500 MB (estimated) about a year ago to 120 GB today. I need to resize all images that is in the folders because my computer is getting full. Quality wise there is no difference, even when running the script multiple times on the same file, no difference. But the idea is to later incorporate this script in the VBA that saves the images in the first place.

Comment: I'm currently struggling with making a recursive loop to get all images in the past, after that is done I need to start on the VBA script and add this there.

Comment: but do you require the files to be named exactly the same after it was scaled?

Comment: No. There is no need for that. But I figured I might as well just replace the files that is there.

Comment: you can't do that because you want to always do the scaling when new files arrive. We need to indicate which have been done already. Let me update my answer with a possible solution for you to consider.

Comment: The files arrive from an email, a VBA code reads the emails I get and if certain things matches then it downloads the file and places it in a folder structure, at this point I have the filename and directory so I can run the resize command from the VBA code directly. New files shouldn't in the future be large when the arrive in my folder structure (according to my plan)

Comment: it is different if it is a once of thing, then you can move all the files to the destination, convert once of and place them in the source again, but you cannot run the script on the files again as it will then attempt re-scaling them again.

Comment: see edit in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this option will place the files back into the original directory with an appended `_scaled` tag in the name, then delete the original file once it exists. Using `findstr` we will only focus on the items without the `_scaled` tag.

```
@echo off
set "source=C:\src"

:start
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b "%source%\*.jpg" ^| findstr /V /R "_scaled"') do (
    call scale.bat -source "%source%\%%~nxa" -target "%source%\%%~na_scaled%%~xa" -max-height 1000 -max-width 1000 -keep-ratio yes -force yes
    if exist "%source%\%%~na_scaled%%~xa" del /Q "%source%\%%~nxa"
    )
(timeout /t 5)>nul && goto :start
```

This is untested, so just update me on the result, obviously do some QA first by creating dummy directory with some files and change source to it.

EDIT, as per your last comment, if this is a once of run and you want to retain the original name, then you could simply move them to a folder, do the conversion and let them land back in the source.

```
@echo off
set "source=C:\src"
set "destination=C:\res1"

move /Y "%source%\*.jpg" "%destination%"
for %%a in ("%destination%\*.jpg") do (
    call scale.bat -source "%destination%\%%~nxa" -target "%source%\%%~nxa" -max-height 1000 -max-width 1000 -keep-ratio yes -force yes
    if exist "%source%\%%~nxa" del /Q "%destination%\%%~nxa"
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

This line indicates that the file might have been moved:

```
Waiting for 0 seconds, press a key to continue ...
/Y "c:\res1\details5.jpg" "c:\src\details5.jpg"
```

It looks like the file, located at "c:\res1\details5.jpg" has been moved to "c:\src" and, in case there already was a file "details5.jpg", then that file has been replaced.

I have the impression that your batchfile is doing the right thing (your batchfile is moving files and in case of already existing, replacing file), while you seem to be expecting new files to arrive.

Comment: That line is because of the echo: `echo /Y "%result_folder_1%\%%~nxa" "%%~a"` this is to confirm that it takes files from res -> source. I'm expecting the file size of the files in the source folder to go from about 2-3 MB to ~ 100 KB. But I realized my error now. The files was moved but I had forgotten to remove the delete line, the line that I had before to delete the source file, the source file that now with the move added became the result file. When I removed the last line of the loop it did exactly what I wanted.